# Export to PDF to a local folder

Tags: asp.net, windows, reporting-services

I have a Asp.net C# windows application where i call a SSRS Report.I want a functionality called " Export to pdf" in my page,and the following pdf must save into a local folder.Is it possible through coding or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

use [WkHtml](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)
or [itextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for better performance in open source projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you are using SOAP to access the report server, you need to build it up yourself. If you are using the report viewer controls or URL access, this functionality should already exist.